# Evaluating a sum $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k}\binom{n}{k}$

Tags: combinatorics

How should I evaluate the sum: $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k}\binom{n}{k}$ ?

I have no relevant observations or partial results so far.

Any kind of help or advice would be truly appreciated!

Comment: What book is this problem from? Are you sure you copied it right, it's not $\sum\frac1{k+1}\binom nk$?

Comment: @bof, I added a probabilistic proof of your identity in the old link.

Answer (score -1):

Use binom of Newton:

$$(1+x)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom nk x^k\stackrel{\text{integ.}}\implies\frac{(1+x)^{n+1}}{n+1}=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk\frac{x^{k+1}}{k+1}+C\;,\;\;C=\text{ constant}$$

Now susbtitute $\;x=0\;$ to find the constant, and then $\;x=1\;$ and do some little algebra.

Comment: Please show the algebra to get from $\sum\frac1{k+1}\binom nk$ to $\sum\frac1k\binom nk.$

Comment: Sorry but is there any relation at all between $\sum\frac1k{n\choose k}$ and $\sum\frac1{k+1}{n\choose k}$? I see none. (Repeating @bof's point.)

Comment: @bof Thanks for pointing the typo, edited. \.

Comment: @did Integrating $\frac{(1+x)^n-1}{x}$ instead should work.

Comment: @Arthur Yes, I already figured out that the sum is equal to $\int_0^1\frac{(1+x)^n-1}xdx.$ Can you integrate that in closed form?

Comment: @bof When I stop to think about it, not as anything other than the sum we want to evaluate, no.

Comment: @SubhadeepDey The answer is clearly _not_ $1$ for $n\geq 2$.

Comment: $$\int_0^1\frac{(1+x)^n-1}xdx=\int_0^1\sum_{k=1}^n\binom nk x^{k-1}\;dx=\left.\sum_{k=1}^n\binom nk\frac1k\cdot x^k\right|_0^1=\sum_{k=1}^n\binom nk\frac1k$$

Comment: @Arthur Is $\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{2^k-1}k$ an improvement over the sum we want to evaluate?

Comment: @Joanpemo That's right, the integral of $\frac{(x+1)^n-1)}x$ will give the correct answer. Are you capable of calculating that integral?

Comment: @Arthur Thank you. Didn't I calculate that integral already in my last comment? Or what do you mean, please?

Comment: Your last comment gave the RHS, which we can't calculate, so we were resorting to that integral to help us

Comment: I substituted $u=x+1$ and got $$\int_1^2\frac{u^n-1}{u-1}du = \int_1^2(1+u+u^2+\cdots+u^{n-1})du = \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{2^k-1}k.$$